# Exception when i tried to run struts 2 application in eclipse galileo IDE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, struts2

I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:342)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspInit(Login_jsp.java:34)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I have the following jar files in WEB-INF-lib :

- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- freemarker-2.3.8.jar
- ognl-2.6.11.jar
- struts2-core-2.0.12.jar
- xwork-2.0.6.jar

I m using Apache Tomcat v6.0 .

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please show your web.xml. Your jars are correct for 2.0.12... if this is a new project then it would be good to use the latest struts2 (ver 2.3.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which you should take care of

- Make sure you have jars includes with same version

as per your post you have different version of different jars like you are using very old version of S2 core and you are using different version of Xcore.

My suggestion is to download [sample application](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi) from S2 home site this will not only give you idea about the structure of S2 application and will give clear idea about jar version being used in the application.

Regarding your exception it seems like container specific jars in your web-application.Since you are using Eclipse as IDE, you should have set the servletcontainer as Target Runtime in the project's properties. This way Eclipse will automatically take all its libraries in the project's buildpath.

Please see following thread for details

- [Tomcat-JSP-issues-td2096791](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Tomcat-JSP-issues-td2096791.html)